# изменить цвета ячеек в таблице

Tags: css, jquery, table

Есть таблица, нужно задать цвет ячеек в колонке, таким образом, чтоб цвет менялся в зависимости от значения в ячейке.по аналогии с тепловой картой!
диапазон цветов: minColor: '#f9f9f9' до maxColor: '#98c76b'

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: почему rgb а не rgba? куда проще варьировать альфа канал по шкале от 0 до 255, чем rgb менять

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как по мне, просто изменяйте альфа канал у цвета от 0 до 1 в зависимости от значения.

```js
$("td").each(function(){     
   let a = +$(this).text()/100;     
   $(this).css('background-color', `rgba(152, 199, 108, ${a})`);
});
```

```css
td {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
tr {
  background-color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+1){
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr><td>10</td><td>100</td></tr>
  <tr><td>25</td><td>0</td></tr>
  <tr><td>50</td><td>0</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала я бы перешел от цветовой модели RGB к HSL. Тогда, задав оттенок и насыщенность раз и навсегда, в переменные minColor и maxColor я бы занес значение яркости, от самой  маскимальной (светлой) до минимальной (темной). Да, именно так, чтобы minColor соотвествовало наименьшей величине.

Затем я бы определился с условиями для каждой колонки. То, что вы хотите, в экселе делается условным форматированием и требует задания условий. Например, должна ли быть наиболее темной ячейка с максимальной величиной в КАЖДОЙ колонке? Или ВО ВСЕХ колонках с величиной одного типа надо выяснить минимальную и максимальную величину? Или цвет ячейки зависит от порогового значения в ячейке (например, больше 75% - темная, и не станет еще темнее даже при значении в 100500%).

Ну а дальше просто. Разбиваем диапазон значений в ячейках (с учетом всех ограничений, если таковые будут) на столько частей, сколько % у вас получилось при вычитании maxColor из minColor, и проходимся скриптом по ячейкам, делая вычисления яркости и подставляя результат в свойства цвета в формате HSL/HSLA.

Например, у вас:

```
в одной ячейке значение 5 (и это минимум. переменная Min), 
в другой 30, 
в третьей 125 (и это максимум, переменная Max), 
цвет должен становиться светлее/темнее равномерно,
minColor = 100%,
maxColor = 70%
```

то скрипт в каждой ячейке сделает как-то так:

```
%SomeVariable% = cell.value / (Max - Min) * 100; // узнаем, какой % значение ячейки составляет от диапазона
%SomeVariable% = %SomeVariable% * (minColor - maxColor) / 100; // узнаем, какой % этот процент составляет от предусмотренного диапазона яркостей
%someOtherVariable% = minColor - %SomeVariable%; //вычитаем этот % из максимума яркости, т.к. нам надо чем больше значение, тем МЕНЬШЕ L.
cell.style.backgroundColor = "HSLA(0,100%," + %someOtherVariable% + "%, 1)"; // задаем цвет.
```